# php : How to send lead forms to salesforce.com api?

Tags: php

I am new to php and salesforce api. I have given an assignment in which I have to send the lead forms to salesforce api. My organization have a salesforce account but I have no idea how to implement salesforce api in php. Can anyone please help me on this?? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would begin by reading over the documentation at http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Integration and particularly the PHP information http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Web_Services_API#PHP

If you are not already used to PHP this seems like it could be a big ask to pull off.

Comment: Hey, I have read it.... But not the getting the authorize, authenticate and call back urls. Can u help me with that??

Comment: Afraid I have not had to implement this particular API before I am not therefore aware of the URLs. SalesForce offer support for this type of enquiry though don't they?